# Slicing a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the DataFrame `data`:

```
                 one  two  three  four
Ohio      2013-01-01    1      2     3
Colorado  2014-01-05    5      6     7
Utah      2015-05-06    9     10    11
New York  2016-10-11   13     14    15
```

I'd like to extract the row using only the criterion that the year is a given year, e.g., something like `data['one'][:][0:4] == '2013'`.  But the command `data['one'][:][0:4]` returns

```
Ohio        2013-01-01
Colorado    2014-01-05
Utah        2015-05-06
New York    2016-10-11
Name: one, dtype: object
```

I thought this is the right thing to do because the command `data['one'][0][0:4]` returns

```
'2013'
```

Why the difference, and what's the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since column `'one'` consists of dates, it'd be best to have pandas recognize it as such, instead of recognizing it as strings.  You can use `pd.to_datetime` to do this:

```
df['one'] = pd.to_datetime(df['one'])
```

This allows you to filter on date properties without needing to worry about slicing strings.  For example, you can check for year using `Series.dt.year`:

```
df['one'].dt.year == 2013
```

Combining this with `loc` allows you to get all rows where the year is 2013:

```
df.loc[df['one'].dt.year == 2013, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition you are looking for is

```
df['one'].str[0:4] == "2013"
```

Basically, you need to tell Pandas to read your column as a string, then operate on the strings from that column.

The way you have it written (`df['one'][:]`), says "give me the column called "one", then give me all of them `[:]`.

Comment: He wants the whole row I believe

Answer (score 0):

`query` works out well too on datetime columns

```
In [13]: df.query('one == 2013')
Out[13]:
            one  two  three  four
Ohio 2013-01-01    1      2     3
```